# Can bootstrap be used along with html, css, js to build apps using phonegap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-cli, phonegap-desktop-app

I dont know much about phonegap except that it can build apps from html, css, js.
My question is whether bootstrap can be used along with html, css, js to build apps using phonegap?

Comment: would this be bootstrap as in http://getbootstrap.com/ ???? cause if so i highly recommend it use it in all my projects never disappoints

Comment: yes its that bootsrap. Thanks. But i didnt get you asking whether it is as in getbootstrap.com. Does something different exist?

Comment: theres various different things know as bootstrap this one is the most well know but as a game developer i come across various frameworks under the name bootstrap so forgive me lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap is a framework which contains CSS and JS files. If you want to build apps using Phonegap, sure you can use Bootstrap as long as you link your HTML file to the Bootstrap files.

Comment: will this be recommended over using another framework such as ionic or framework7?

Answer (score 3):

Since Twitter Bootstrap is just a library including CSS and javascript, it is bound to work.

**make sure that you have linked all the bootstrap libraries(ie., the css file, js file and jquery file).**

I have developed a cordova app with bootstrap library and its as it says.. Mobile first! :-)

Thank You.

Comment: Hi, can i ask will be any advantage over using some other framework like ionic or framework7?

Comment: of course! they are libraries which have a lot of functionalities of android and iOS. They also have components which looks like a stock android app(the aesthetics).

Answer (score 2):

Kotak,

Phone-gap supports bootstrap for UI design,
Basically Bootstrap is use as a responsive web framework. Like all responsive web frameworks is to adapt your view layer to the device doing the viewing.Its Giving you different presentations for mobile phones, tablets, PCs, etc.
as we use this -
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
For JS.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/
For css and html.

so as per our requirement we can use that.